# Timer even outside the app

Tags: android

I'm trying to find a way to implement this.

basically it's a timer say like in farm ville or such games that count even when you exit the app.

how do I implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to keep a service running to keep track of these things when your app is not visible in the Activity stack.  See here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 1):

Put all logic that's supposed to work even if your app is not visible inside service. Use AlarmManager, Timer there. Service has the same priority as visible Activity, so it won't be killed.

Comment: sorry, for some reason went directly to the answer under this   :s, but this one also correct